# how do i delete <?= $var ?> in a chain with php

Tags: php, url, variables, str-replace

how do i delete `<?= $var ?>` from a chain (a url in this case).

Here is what I already tried:

```
$link = str_replace("<?= $var ?>", "", $link);
```

but when i `echo $link;`, nothing appear.
(I think its a problem with the open and close php tags)

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars($link)`, or do a view-source to see exactly what's being output. remember, if you're viewing this in a browser in an html context, the browser is going to try to render ANYTHING that looks like a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "chain" did you mean "string"?

If nothing else, you'll need single quotes to stop `$var` from getting interpolated:

```
$link = str_replace('<?= $var ?>', '', $link);
```

I would also recommend breaking up the characters that look like PHP open/close tags, for good measure:

```
$link = str_replace('<?' . '= $var ?' . '>', '', $link);
```

And have a think about what you're using this string for, and whether it's *really* a good idea to have PHP code in it. **Because it's probably not.**

Also be aware that you may not be interpreting the results correctly. Usually we view the output of PHP in a web browser, and web browsers like to assume that what they are receiving from your server is HTML. Text that begins `<` and ends `>` is going to be interpreted as an HTML tag and not rendered verbatim; therefore, use your browser's "View Source" function to see what you *really* get.

Answer (score 2):

You can use single quotes which don't parse the variables:

```
$link = str_replace('<?= $var ?>', "", $link);
```